# get price in shipment email template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, email-templates, special-price, shipment

I need to get customer order product price for Shipment email template in  configurable products.

I had added  magento-sales/templates/email/items/shipment/default.php

```
$priceHelper = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

<?php echo  $priceHelper->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false); ?>
```

From above code i'm getting default 1st child price. I need to get customer order product price.

Please advise me